# asp classic pass form of type=date

Tags: jquery, forms, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

I have run into an issue here. The form of type DATE is not passing to my ASP Classic page.

```
<input type="date" name="theDate">
```

And the asp side, does not get the date sent to it.

This is a demo page. http://www.cffcs.com/stuff/one/Pick.asp
This is the Form.

```
<form action="process.asp" method="post" name="RegForm" onSubmit="xmlhttpPost('process.asp', 'RegForm', 'RegDiv', '&lt;img src=\'graph/moreajax.gif\'&gt;'); return false;" class="form-2" style="width:90%;">  
<input tabindex="7" type="date" name="Birthdate" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"  style="height:30px;"/> 
<input tabindex="9" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Create">
</form>
<div id="RegDiv"></div>
```

This is the process.asp part of it.

```
<%
mydate = CDate(Request.Form("Birthdate"))
response.Write mydate&"<br />"
response.write(FormatDateTime(mydate,1) & "<br />")
%>
```

In the JS file, that is included in the page. I had to add in the following on line 63

```
|| elemType == "DATE"
```

Once that was added in, it went to working.

That takes care of this one.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. What do you expect us to do with this? Classic ASP will not treat this input any differently, just check the raw request being sent when the `<form>` is submitted using inbuilt browser web dev tools *(usually shortcut F12)*.

Comment: Please provide code that would allow us to reproduce your issue. Seems likely that the form method is set to `get`.

Comment: I am having some issues, and it is hard to post code, when I cannot even get it to work. It is only like it is not sending to the processing asp page. I will post back once I find out what is going on.

Comment: @WayneBarron that is the whole point of a [mcve]. Providing a bare bones example using as simplistic approach as possible that recreates the issue will not only help us better answer the question, but you understand the problem.

Comment: Updated the information with code and other details.

Comment: @WayneBarron well straight away I see one key piece of information you didn't mention, this isn't a standard form submission...can you provide more details of `xmlHttpPost()` JavaScript function?, again not included in the code. The fact you appear to be using some sort of xhr request to submit the form means there are lots of reasons why the input might not be reaching the ASP page.

Comment: I thought I had posted that it is jquery, sorry about that. Any idea's on why it will not post?

Comment: This was resolved on the outside. Had to add in a simple elemType == "DATE" to the JS file... All is good now.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code, it should list out every POSTed value:

```
for each item in Request.Form
    Response.Write "<p>" & item & " = " & Request.Form( item ) & "</p>"
next
```

if you don't see your field, make sure it resides within FORM tags in your mark up

Comment: It is not picking up on the type=date field at all. It listed every other field, but NOT the Type="Date" field.

Comment: @WayneBarron Is the field contained inside the `<form>` tags?

Comment: Absolutely. It is nestled between the Gender and Password.

Comment: @WayneBarron ok, but from the code you posted we can't see that.

Comment: Lanky, give me a few minutes and I will TRY to get something to you.
Right now, heck, I cannot even load a subfolder into the brower, it is not finding anything.... I am going to reboot, and see if I can make this blasted thing work. It is a pain, when I want to provide information, but can't because nothing works..... Just want to scream right now, I have never gone through this mess before, while designing a site. Just pissed right now.

Comment: Updated the post.